# How do I modify a portion of a vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am wondering if I'm missing something basic involving vector manipulation. Let's say I have the following:

```
(def xs [9 10 11 12 13]) 
(def idx [0 2]) 
(def values [1 3])
```

If I want to return the vector `[1 10 3 12 13]` in Matlab, I would write `xs(idx) = values`.
In Clojure, is there a primitive way of achieving this? Right now I'm using the following function:

```
(defn xinto [seq idx val]
  (apply assoc seq (interleave idx val)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: I can offer no code beyond the already given suggestions. `assoc` _is_ the appropriate primitive but it wants the indexes and values passed individually as you already see. You can either build a sequence of index value pairs as you do and use `apply` or recursively do the assoc using `reduce` as suggested by amalloy and mikera. Under the hood the multi index-value version of assoc is recursive anyway. I would consider the `reduce` options more idiomatic.

Comment: I think your solution is pretty much the best.

Comment: `apply assoc` and `interleave` are probably the best choice when all you want to do is specifically set an index without regard to its previous value. Most of the time I suspect you'll want to do something more complicated, and then this "trick" won't work at all; that's why I suggested using `reduce`, which is more general.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit awkward because you've split up `idx` and `values` into two seqs, when they're conceptually a map of indexes to values. So if you'll permit me a little creative modification of your data format:

```
(def x [9 10 11 12 13]) 
(def changes {0 1, 2 3}) 

(defn xinto [v changes]
  (reduce (fn [acc [k v]]
            (assoc acc k v))
          v
          changes))

(xinto x changes) ;; gets the result you want
```

If you generate `idx` and `values` in some weird way that it's not convenient to group them together, you can group them later with `(map list idx values)` and then use my `xinto` implementation with that.

Comment: Consider using `transient`, `assoc!`, and `persistent!` here.

Comment: @seh Uh, I guess you could do that, but it hardly seems worth the effort. If either the initial vector or the set of changes to make is small, the time needed to transition to/from a transient will outweigh the gains of using one.

Comment: or (zipmap idx values) instead of (map list idx values)

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use [reduce](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reduce) for this:

```
(reduce 
  (fn [old [i v]] (assoc old i v))
   x   
  (map vector idx values))
```

However, if you really want to do this a lot (Matlab-style) then I'd suggest creating some helper macros / functions to create some kind of DSL for vector manipulation.

Comment: I was trying to follow the example code but it seemed to be missing the original vector 'x'. I edited the example to be the three argument form of reduce for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Could not find something better.

In the core sequence functions there is `replace`, but it works on values, not on keys. 
So,

```
(replace {9 2} x)
```

Would return

```
[2 10 11 12 13]
```

If you plan to do math related things in Clojure, I also propose you have a look at [Incanter](http://data-sorcery.org/contents/). It has a lot of APIs to manipulate mathematical data.