# In clojure, how to apply a function to selected items in a [large] vector

Tags: matlab, clojure

I have a vector `v`

```
(def v [1 2 5 8 4 3 8 9 3])
```

I want to apply function `myfn`

```
(defn myfn [x] (+ 1 x))
```

to selected items that I have their indexes `idx`

```
(def idx [3 5])
```

I've seen [How do I modify a portion of a vector in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086818/how-do-i-modify-a-portion-of-a-vector-in-clojure) and it is not exactly what I need.

Like what you do in MATLAB

```
v = [1 2 5 8 9 3];
idx = [3 5];
v(idx) = myfn(v(idx));
```

Comment: sorry, @yoda, now it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vectors in clojure are associative, so you can do something like this: `(reduce #(update-in %1 [%2] myfn) v idx)`

Answer (score 3):

*Updated because I misinterpreted the question.*

Here's another solution:

```
(apply assoc v (mapcat #(vector % (myfn (v %))) idx))
```

that is, build up an argument list of index/new-value pairs to `assoc`. I think mange's solutions is probably better though.

---

*Original, incorrect solution*

Don't forget that vector `v` is itself a function of its indices. So:

```
(map myfn (map v idx))
```

or:

```
(->> idx (map v) (map myfn))
```

or:

```
(map (comp myfn v) idx)
```

I'm sure there's also a very clever answer involving `juxt` :)

Comment: This will return the modified indexes as a new seq rather than updating them within the original vector.

Comment: Oops. The question doesn't specify the output, so it was easy to misinterpret.

Answer (score 2):

You mention "a [large] vector", so do you care about performance? You may want to find out about [transients](http://clojure.org/Transients):

```
(persistent!
  (reduce (fn [v i] (assoc! v i (myfn (get v i))))
          (transient v)
          idx))
```

Or, if you prefer looping style, this does the same thing:

```
(loop [v (transient v), [i & is :as idx] idx]
  (if (empty? idx)
    (persistent! v)
    (recur (assoc! v i (myfn (get v i))) is)))
```

Comment: This is certainly superior when updating many indexes. What is the cost of `transient`/`persistent!`? I assume that for a small number of indexes this would have a slightly more overhead.

Comment: They're advertised as O(1), and they do seem to be pretty fast. The cost is more in the restrictions on the code: you have to use a different set of primitives and can't allow other threads to access the data between `transient` and `persistent!`. But transients are a good match for a small piece of code like this that does multiple edits of the data structure in a loop.

Comment: Yeah, `O(1)` just means constant overhead, so negligible for large numbers of mutations, but maybe significant for smaller numbers. I've never really used transients, but they seem super handy like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
(let [sidx (set idx)]
  (vec                        ;(sidx i)
    (map-indexed (fn [i x] (if (contains? sidx i) (myfn x) x)) v)))
```